# PHP PDO Multiple Table join

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have multiple tables and I want to access the fields in a specific table. Here are the table `schemas`:

[image]

Each `tbl_acct` has one `tbl_unit`. A `tbl_unit` has many `tbl_groups` and a `tbl_groupcontact` consist of the contacts and the related group. Every time I log in, I set a session where `$_SESSION['unitid'] = $row['unitid'];`.

What I wanted to do is to access the fields in the `tbl_contacts`. For now my code is here:

```
$data = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_groups LEFT JOIN tbl_groupcontact ON tbl_groups.id=tbl_groupcontact.group_id WHERE tbl_groups.unitid = ?");
$data->execute(array($_SESSION['unitid']));
foreach ($data as $row) {
    echo $row['fname'] . " " . $row['lname']. "<br />"; 
}
```

As you can see, I can related the `tbl_groups` and `tbl_groupcontact` in my code however, I can't get the fields in the `tbl_contacts`. Am I missing something here? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to join another table.

```
SELECT tbl_contacts.*
FROM tbl_groups
INNER JOIN tbl_groupcontact ON tbl_groupcontact.group_id = tbl_groups.id 
INNER JOIN tbl_contacts ON tbl_contacts.id = tbl_groupcontact.contact_id
WHERE tbl_groups.unitid = ?
```

No need for (slower) `LEFT JOIN` btw - use it when you want to retrieve records from (left-side) table even when there's no match found in joined (right-side) table (it's columns will be filled with nulls in this case).

Comment: Works very well. Thank you for the tip!